# Yii2 change active database based on controller

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to change yii2 active database in controller.
What I have so far:

```
        Yii::$app->db = new yii\db\Connection([
            'dsn' => 'dblib:host='.$company->host.';port=1433;dbname=Interface',
            'username' => $company->db_user,
            'password' => $company->db_password,
        ]);
        Yii::$app->db->open();
        $users = User::find()->all();
```

Can I change active database like that and then start using models in new database and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple databases in the config file with both databases referring to different objects. Use the object with the respective database you want to use.

For example:
If you have two databases defined in the config file `db` and `db1`.
Then you can just use `db1` instead of `db` wherever you need.